# How to position modal dialog adjacent to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am using a jquery supplied dialog modal popup,
see: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message
It seems that by default the dialog box appears in the middle of the frame. I would like to have the modal box next to a button on my webpage. How would I go about doing this? What code would I add?

Thanks!

The code for the modal box is in the link

Comment: Please, check jQueryUI API documentation.. Here you are: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: The API provides several position options for you to select from and implement. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Answer (score 0):

From ui dialog documentation

```
    // Getter
    var position = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position" );

    // Setter
    $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "position",{ my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: button } );
```